# IEEE 802.3 Clause 28

Tags: autonegotiation

Where in clause 28 of the IEEE 802.3 standard does it define what should happen when auto-negotiation fails?

I thought this would be defined but can't find reference to it in the standard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*28.1.1 Scope* states

> A device that fails to respond to the FLP Burst
> sequence by returning only the NLP sequence is treated as a 10BASE-T compatible device.

See *Figure 28-17 Receive state diagram*. The very first twisted-pair PHY used (normal) *link pulses* (NLPs) to indicate link availability to its partner. Unless there's an indication of mutually supported better modes, the basic mode is 10BASE-T half duplex.

*Figure 28-18 Arbitration state diagram* then shows the Autonegotiation phase using fast link pulses (FLPs). Failing that, the link stays at 10BASE-T HDX.

[edit] Capability detection between 100BASE-TX and 10BASE-T (and historically, 100BASE-T4) is defined in *28.2.3.1 Parallel detection function*. Its footnote states

> When selecting the highest common denominator through the Parallel Detection function, only the halfduplex
> mode corresponding to the selected PMA may automatically be detected.

Comment: Thanks. What in 28-17 denotes that 10BASE-T HDX is the basic mode? Also when I interpret Figure 28-18 it goes back to ABILITY DETECT state continually? What am I getting wrong? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I added the HDX bit to the answer. Without FLPs, the ABILITY DETECT state isn't ever entered.

Comment: That's great thanks. I've re-read the clause taking note of your comments and I get it now. I'd misunderstood Parallel Detection function and not noticed Note 2 in 28.2.3.1 until you pointed it out. Thank you ever so much for your help!